# Visual studio code "ng serve" command fails with "Cannot redefine property: file"

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I created an angular project in visual studio code(version 1.81.1). but when I try to run the program using "ng serve" command give below error.(Node version : 20.6.0,npm version : 10.0.0)

`Cannot redefine property: File`

[image: This is the error message]

Execution policies set as below

[image: execution policies]

Can give any reason for the issue?

Comment: Well, according to the error message your version of node.js does not match your version of Angular - each Angular version requires/is supported on a particular range of node versions. You can have multiple versions of node installed and switch between them. Google it.

Comment: It could be due to the Node.js version. As you can see it's not supported. Try to downgrade Node.js version to 18.10.0. You can check this : https://angular.io/guide/versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an issue with node 20.6 that breaks babel. The fix for node has landed but not been released yet.

- [issue for node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/49497)
- [issue for Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15927)

Downgrading to any previous version of Node (below 20.6) will fix the  issue.

---

Babel has introduced a workaround in [`7.22.17`](https://github.com/babel/babel/releases/tag/v7.22.17) with [#15947](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/) with allow Angular to run with 20.6.

Answer (score 3):

When I uninstalled node version 20.6.1 and installed node version 18.17.1, issue was fixed

Answer (score 1):

upgrade to 20.6.1 and the problem will dissapear